# Cleaning file upload (FileList) won't call 'on change' event

Tags: javascript, html

I have a file input that when it has files appears a little icon to remove all selected files. The problem is that I have tried a lot of things to clean the file input but the 'on change' event is never called. It's only called when I press the input and change the file I want, but if I clean my FileList it should count as a 'change' or am I mistaken?

So my question is: What is the best method (in this case) to clean my file input with a simple click on my icon and still get 'on change' event?

Here is my code:

```html
...
<input id="images_file" multiple="multiple" class="file_upload" type="file">

<label for="images_file"><i class="fas fa-camera"></i> Adicionar imagens</label>
<span id="clean_images_file" class="remove_selected_files"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></span>
...
```

```js
function fileUpload(){
    $( '.file_upload' ).each( function(){
        var $input   = $(this),
            $label   = $input.next('label'),
            $removeFiles = $label.next('span'),
            labelVal = $label.html();
            clone = $input.clone(true);

    $removeFiles.on('click', function(){
       $input.replaceWith(clone);
       $removeFiles.hide();
    })

    $input.on( 'change', function(e){
       alert("change");
       var fileName = '';

       if (this.files) {
          $removeFiles.show("fast");
          if (this.files.length > 1) {
              fileName = `${this.files.length} files added` ;
          } else {
              fileName = "1 file added" ;
          }
       }

       if( fileName )
           $label.html( fileName );
       else
           $label.html( labelVal );
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to clear an `<input type="file">` is to set its value to `null`:

```
const formInput = document.querySelector('input[type=file]');
formInput.value = null;
```

Unfortunately, setting `value` directly doesn't cause a `change` event to be dispatched.

A workaround to this would be to fire you own event when you clear the input:

```
formInput.value = null
formInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true });
```

In jQuery that would look, I believe, like this:

```js
const $fileInput = $('input[type=file]');

$('button').on('click', () => {
  $fileInput.val(null);
  $fileInput.trigger('change', { bubbles: true });
})

let i = 0;
$fileInput.on('change', () => console.log(`${$fileInput.prop('files').length} file(s) added`));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" multiple>
<button type="button">Clear</button>
```